# ¿Cómo imprimir datos guardados en Base de Datos en archivo generado con FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf, cpanel

Tengo el siguiente código y funciona perfectamente en servidor local imrpimiendo los datos en un documento PDF generado con FPDF, pero cuando lo subí en mi CPanel, no imprime ninguno de los resultados guardados en las tablas.
Sólo aparece el encabezado y el resultado de una consulta SQL aparte que se encarga de traer la suma de los valores de dos campos, pero el resto de los datos traídos de la BD de no puede visualizarse, y tampoco salen mensajes de error.
Por favor, les agradecería que pudieran orientarme en cómo imprimir los datos de las tablas y así poder llenar los registros de la tabla impresa en el documento PDF.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('../modelo/conexion.php');
require_once('../modelo/consultas.php');

$consultas = new Consultas();
$rows = $consultas -> getTemporal();
$totales = $consultas -> ejecutadas();

Class PDF extends FPDF{

 function Header(){

    global $title;

    $this -> Image('../img/logotipo.png', 8, 3, 120);
    $this -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $this -> Cell(95, 10);
    $this -> SetTextColor(110, 66, 56);
    $this -> Text(135, 20, utf8_decode('Cuadro de Seguimiento Producción'), 0, 0, 'C');
    $this -> SetFont('Arial', 'BI', 9);
    $this -> Text(310, 20, utf8_decode('Fecha: ' . date("Y-m-d")), 0, 0, 'C');
    $this -> Ln(35);

}

function Footer(){

    $this -> SetY(-15);

    $this -> SetFont('Arial', 'I', 10);

    $this -> SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $this -> SetDrawColor(110, 66, 56);
    $this -> SetLineWidth(1);
    $this -> Line(337, 192, 17, 192);

    $this -> Cell(0, 10, utf8_decode('Página ' . $this -> PageNo() . '/{nb}'), 0, 0, 'C');

   }

}

$doc = new PDF();

if($_GET['v']){

 $title = 'Previsualización Seguimiento Producción';

} else {

  $title = 'Seguimiento Producción';

}

$doc -> SetTitle(utf8_decode($title));

$doc -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$doc -> SetFillColor(255, 204, 0);

$doc -> AliasNbPages();
$doc -> AddPage('L', 'Legal');

$doc -> SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$doc -> SetY(38);
$doc -> SetX(10);
$doc -> Cell(30, 10, 'Proyecto', 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(39, 10, 'Actividad', 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(55, 10, utf8_decode('Tarea Específica'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(28, 10, utf8_decode('Responsable'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(33, 10, utf8_decode('Talento'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(20, 10, utf8_decode('Fecha'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(15, 10, utf8_decode('Inicio'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(15, 10, utf8_decode('Final'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(15, 10, utf8_decode('Total'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(38, 10, utf8_decode('Descripción'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(22, 10, utf8_decode('Realizado'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Cell(27, 10, utf8_decode('Total Ejecución'), 1, 0, 'C', true);
$doc -> Ln();

$doc -> SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$doc -> SetFont('Arial', '', 9);

foreach($rows as $row){

    $alto = null;

    if(strlen($row['descripcion']) <= 20){

        $alto = 10;
        $altoCell = $alto;

    } elseif(strlen($row['descripcion']) > 20 && strlen($row['descripcion']) <= 45){

        $alto = 10;
        $altoCell = $alto * 2;

    } elseif(strlen($row['descripcion']) > 45 && strlen($row['descripcion']) < 85){

        $alto = 10;
        $altoCell = $alto * 3;

    }

    $doc -> SetX(10);
    $doc -> Cell(30, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['proyecto']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(39, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['actividad']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(55, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['tareaEspecifica']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(28, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['responsable']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(33, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['talento']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(20, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['fechaPauta']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(15, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['horaPauta']), 1, 0, 'C');

    $doc -> SetX(298);
    $doc -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
    $doc -> Cell(22, $altoCell, utf8_decode(ucwords($row['realizacion'])), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
    $doc -> SetX(230);
    $doc -> Cell(15, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['horaFinal']), 1, 0, 'C');
    $doc -> Cell(15, $altoCell, utf8_decode($row['tiempoTotal']), 1, 0, 'C');
    

    $doc -> SetX(260);
    $doc -> MultiCell(38, $alto, utf8_decode($row['descripcion']), 1, 'L');
    
    $doc -> Ln(0);

}

$doc -> SetX(320);

foreach($totales as $row){
        
    $num = (int)$row;
    $total = round($num / 60, 2);
    $decimales = (string)$total;
    $decimal = substr($decimales, strpos($decimales, "."));
    $decimal = (float)$decimal * 60;
    $decimal = (int)round($decimal);
    $entero = (int)$total;

    if($decimal >= 60){

        $decimal = $decimal % 60;
        $decimal = "0$decimal";

    }

    if($decimal < 10){

        $decimal = "0$decimal";

    }

    $doc -> SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $doc -> Cell(27, 10, utf8_decode($entero.':'.$decimal.' horas'), 1, 0, 'C');

    if($row){

        break;

    }

}

$doc -> Output("I", "Cuadro de Seguimiento ".date("Y-m-d").".pdf", true);

if(!$_GET['v']){

    $vacio = $consultas -> truncateTempTable();

}

?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿La consulta funciona y el PDF se genera pero no muestra una parte de los datos? Si es eso, haz una verificación, con `var_dump` de los datos que estás usando para crear el PDF.

Comment: La consulta funciona en el Localhost, pero en el CPanel no muestra los resultados traídos de la consulta y tampoco me muestra si existe algún error a través del error_reporting()

Comment: La version php de mi servidor en 7.4

Comment: ¿En el cPanel? No entiendo lo que quieres decir con eso. ¿La conexión a la base de datos funciona ahí? ¿Lo verificaste? ¿Hablas de un servidor remoto?

Comment: Sí, es un servidor remoto. Lo que suceda en que en local todo funciona correctamente, pero en el servidor remoto (CPanel) no. La conexión está modificada para que funcione correctamente, y lo hace, pero los datos de la tabla que están barrido con un foreach para poder imprimirlos, no se ven en la tabla.

Comment: Pero ¿subiste la base de datos al servidor remoto? ¿Probaste simplemente a consultar la tabla y verificar si los datos existen allí?

Comment: Para resumirte todo: el formulario donde registro los datos que se guardarán en la tabla y que deberían verse en el pdf, hay un campo de selección donde sí se muestran los datos para poder seleccionar, o sea que la conexión está perfecta. Probé y nada de lo que coloco dentro del foreach del código de mi pregunta se imprime, sólo lo que está afuera del primer foreach es visible.

Comment: ¿Es esto lo que no es visible: `foreach($totales as $row){`? ¿Hiciste un `var_dump($totales);` para depurar tus datos? ¿Qué muestra ese `var_dump`?

Comment: No, el foreach que no se muestra es foreach($rows as $row). Nada de lo que está adentro de ese barrido es visible. Probé colocar una celda que imprimiera un texto cualquiera y tampoco salía sino hasta que borré el foreach.

Comment: Pues eso, `var_dump($rows);` y dinos lo que muestra. Se trata de depurar aquello que no funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias y disculpa tanto. Voy a probar esto y mostraré lo que salga apenas pueda.